# D3 : Collapsible Graph

Tags: d3.js, visualization, graph-visualization

I was trying to plot a multi-level hierarchy of a graph using D3. The idea is: for the graph, I have multilevel clusters (level 0 is the set of vertices of graph, level 1 is clustering done on level 0 nodes, level 2 is clustering done on level 1 nodes, and so on), hence the multilevel cluster part is a tree, while level 0 nodes form a graph.
I want to show tree part as a collapsible (to the relevant cluster), but still show edges among the level 0 nodes. Something like if the orange nodes in [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130) could have edges between them.
Has anyone attempted this? Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem, but don't yet have the d3 artistry to solve it.  Did you have any success?

Comment: I started modifying the code, but didn't finish it. My approach was to dynamically add/remove nodes and edges from javascript and load the new graph. You just have to be careful not to change the numbers of the existing nodes, otherwise the change event is jumpy.